Nx monorepo build pulling in packages from other folders
I have a typescript monorepo using nx. I have a /frontends folder and a /services folder each with a couple of project folders, and the build all works correctly. I use TypeScript and node 20. I use pnpm as a package manager. (I started with a sample project at https://nx.dev/ so it follows their patterns). So far everything fine.
I have a standalone angular project (angular 9, it's deprecated) that is another front end and I want to move it into the monorepo as well. I can move the project verbatim into a new subfolder of /frontends and redo the pnpm install to get the packages, but the build command which works totally fine in standalone mode suddenly fails because the builder is somehow referencing node_modules two parent folders up from this project.
I assumed it was something is tsconfig.json but it's pretty standard and actually matches a different frontend which builds just fine. I'm baffled where else to look, I've tried dozens of tsconfig.json (and tsconfig.app.json in angular).
tsconfig.json in /frontend/thisproject
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"]
  }
}

build command:
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=14144 --openssl-legacy-provider" && ng build --prod


ERROR in ../../../node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1025:21 - error TS1110: Type expected.

1025         : K extends `${number}`
                         ~~~
../../../node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1026:24 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

1026             ? 'length' extends keyof T
                            ~~~~~~~
../../../node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1026:38 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1026             ? 'length' extends keyof T
                                          ~

